# Access form elements of wrapped component in HOC?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to build an HOC, in which i want to access the form elements present in the Wrapped Component.

```
import React from 'react';

const hoc = (WrappedComponent) => (props) => {

    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <WrappedComponent { ...props }></WrappedComponent>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
};

export { hoc };
```

In this HOC, i want access each element from the WrappedComponent. Can anyone guide me the way to implement this functionality

Comment: What do you mean by "access"?

Comment: I want to generate references and pass them as props of all the form elements in the Wrapped Component

Comment: You'll need to use `React.forwardRef` to pass a ref as a prop.

Comment: Can i implement that in HOC wrapping a form component

Comment: I don't see why not. Have a go!

Comment: But that is not a fowardRef? I found an article that might help https://dev.to/justincy/using-react-forwardref-and-an-hoc-on-the-same-component-455m

Comment: Normally i will do with both  React.Children.map()  and React.cloneElement(). How access wrapped component elements like these in HOC?

Comment: Neither of those is in your current question.